# Flutter listview.separator item click

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter, android-studio-3.0, listviewitem

I'm creating a flutter project. And I want to add clicklistener on items. But I don't know how to do it. Here is my `ListView.separator` function

```
ListView.separated(
        itemCount: _listChat.length,
        itemBuilder:
            (context, index)=>Container(
          child: _chatItem(_listChat[index] ),
        ),
        separatorBuilder: (context, index)=>Divider(
          color: Colors.black12,
        ),
      ),
```

If someone has a method, I will be glad to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ListView.separated(
        itemCount: _listChat.length,
        itemBuilder:
            (context, index)=>InkWell(onTap: () {}, child: Container(
          child:  _chatItem(_listChat[index] )),
        ),
        separatorBuilder: (context, index)=>Divider(
          color: Colors.black12,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try and keep you informed.

Comment: You should check the checkmark to mark your question answered.